# About using python mutiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to open more `Chrome` windows with `selenium` in mutiprocessing pool. Now, the windows are opened but programming is not run.

This is my code as below:

```
import time
from PIL import Image
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from threading import Thread,Event
from multiprocessing import Process,Pool
from cookiesinterpark.cookiespool.db import *

class interpark():
    def __init__(self,account,password):
        self.account = account
        self.password = password
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.url ='https://ticket.interpark.com/Gate/TPLogin.asp?CPage=B&MN=Y&tid1=main_gnb&tid2=right_top&tid3=login&tid4=login'
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20)

    def login(self):
        self.browser.maximize_window()
        self.browser.delete_all_cookies()
        self.browser.get(self.url)
        username = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'UID')))
        password = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'PWD')))
        username.send_keys(self.account)
        password.send_keys(self.password)
        self.browser.execute_script("javascript:login();")
        try:
            alert = self.browser.switch_to_alert()
            if alert:
                alert.accept()
                print('{}：'.format(self.account))
                self.DealCaptcha()
            else:
                pass
        except:
            pass

    def run(self):
        self.login()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=3)
    cnn = RedisClient('account', 'interpark')
    accounts_usernames = cnn.usernames()
    for username in accounts_usernames:
        password = cnn.get(username)
        p = pool.apply_async(interpark, args=(username,password))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/interparkOK/cookiesinterpark/login/interpark/Captcha/interparktest.py", line 152, in <module>
    p = pool.apply_async(interpark, args=(username,password))
  File "C:\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 355, in apply_async
    raise ValueError("Pool not running")
ValueError: Pool not running
```

I considered `Threading` to solve the problem, but looking at questions about `selenium webdriver` it seems that it can't support multithreading.

How could I solve this?

Comment: `with Pool(processes=3) as p: p.apply_async()`. You just need to start it.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, try this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=3)
    cnn = RedisClient('account', 'interpark')
    accounts_usernames = cnn.usernames()
    for username in accounts_usernames:
        password = cnn.get(username)
        p = pool.apply_async(interpark, args=(username,password))
    pool.close()  # deindented
    pool.join()  # deindented
```

You had that error because you closed the pool in your for loop.